# 2D Array value changes leaking to other values in the array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int maxProfit(vector<int>& prices){
    
    int rows=4;
    int cols=prices.size();
    vector<vector<int>> profits(rows,vector<int>(cols,0));
    int tempans=0;
    
    for(int i=1;i<rows;i++){
        int MIP=-prices[0];
        for(int j=1;j<cols;j++){


            //eitherr transact on tht day or not...
            //nt transacting means profits of previous transactions on tht day...
            //or transact tht day i.e ....sell and try diff buys
            //when day 1 ,m={0}..profits[0]= no day no trsansaction
            //also only 2 variables chhanging..prives[j](is constant) -  prices[m]+profits[i-1][m](variable)
            //check max(MIP,-prices[j-1]+profits[i-1][m])MIP is Maxium intermediate Profits..
            

            //tempans=max(profits[i][j-1],(MIP+prices[j]));
            profits[i][j]=max(profits[i][j-1],(MIP+prices[j]));
            MIP=max(MIP,(-prices[j]+profits[i-1][j]));
           
        }
    }
    return profits[rows-1][cols-1];
    
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v{2,5,7,1,4,3,1,3};
    int maxprofit=maxProfit(v);
    cout<<maxprofit;
    return 0;
}
```

when debugging the program I found, when iterating through the ith row , (i+1)th row values start changing.
Nowhere in the code I am setting values for i+1th row.

> This doesn't happen if I use 2D vector with same logic instead of a
> array.

**For example,
for the given input in main(), when iterating through 2nd row, midway the 3rd row values start changing. Why this unexpected behaviour**

Comment: Why do your i and j loop start at 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Start with the most minimal input that replicates this behavior, and use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. When you see the unexpected change happen, what are the values of all indexes?

Comment: Or are you simply forgetting thst your loop start from index `1` for your arrays/vectors whose index of course is zero-based?

Comment: starting from 1 is is just for my convenience. I already verified it doesn't have any ill affect on my code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude already did tht, iterating through the second row after half the columns are scanned, the i+1th that is row 3rd starts getting filled with tempans variable values.
i.e after profits[2][6] , profits[3][0] changes from 0 to 5. (UB)

Comment: @rushikeshchaskar *starting from 1 is just for my convenience* -- And a huge reason for off-by-one bugs.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can u please let me know how is it causing UB /bugs in my program. Cause I am unable to find any ill affects of it. Thank u

Comment: @rushikeshchaskar --I see no such behavior when I run your code.  Again, how are you verifying that what you are seeing is actually happening?

Comment: With the code you show, `profits[3][0]` is never modified (or at least its value doesn't change from `0`). See e.g. [here on the compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/48fa3r91W), with added code to display `profits` after each and every iteration of the inner loop. Changing the vector to a (valid fixed-size) array (e.g. `int profits[4][8] = { 0 };`) doesn't change the behavior.